# Trying to receive data with Ajax from PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm trying to receive data with this ajax:

```
        $('#NotesModal').on('click', function() {
            var PropertyId = $(this).data("id");                     

            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "processes/view-note2.php?id="+PropertyId,
                contentType: "charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", // added dataType
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.notes); // renders green
                    alert ("Data received");
                    //$('.modal-body').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id']) && strlen($_GET['id'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        include('../conf/conn.php');

        mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

        $sql = "SELECT PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_NOTES FROM property WHERE PROPERTY_ID = ".$id."";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $notes = $row['PROPERTY_NOTES'];

                echo json_encode(array('notes'=>$notes));

                return;

            }
        }
    }

?>
```

If a run `http://localhost/testproject/processes/view-note2.php?id=6` I can see the object pretty well created:

> {"notes":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
>   Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor."}

I have already tried several techniques for hours without any results. Please.

Comment: `contentType: "charset=utf-8",` — That is not a valid content-type … but you are making a GET request, so there is no content to describe the type of anyway.

Comment: `data: data` — If you look in the developer tools in your browser, you should see an error message telling you that `data` is undefined. That is your problem.

Comment: @Clinton — `?php>`?! That's nonsense.

Comment: provide your HTML code, please.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't see any error in the developer tool. I also comment the line "data: data," and nothing. The HTML is fine, the modal is working. I'm supposed to be able to see my data in the console. I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the response you got in the network tab? (dev. tools, chrome)

Answer (score 0):

First you should try it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "processes/view-note2.php?id=6", // or testproject/processes/view-note2.php?id=6
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

If it's ok, then you can add more features.